# How To Open Three Teminals( Process) at a time

Tags: linux, bash, vi

Please tell me How to open three terminal at time , so that my project would be executed easily without opening the three terminal three times and then running the three exe file . please how do we do this by script ie opening three terminal and executing three exe file.

Comment: So, do you, or do you not want to open 3 terminals ?

Answer (score 1):

Run the terminals in the background:

```
xterm -e exe1 & xterm -e exe2 & xterm -e exe3 &
```

You migh also need the xterm's `-hold` switch if you want to see the output of the exe's after they finish.

Comment: Thanks so much brother and  my most of the time is saving now ,bcz of your help